# How could the likes count could be retrieved from public posts using an application token?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

I have an application which is able to retrieve many public posts with a particular keyword `#ps4` using `/search?q=%23ps4&fields=likes.limit(1).summary(true)`.

Somehow these posts have no `likes.summary` object (actually no `like` objects at all), the only exception being posts coming from public profiles.

I don't need the details of the likes, just the count to allow anyone to be selected as the winner of an event.

Is there another way to retrieve the count?

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no way to get the likes without having the user install an application that authorizes it.